# Only display specific columns in a table that I have retrieved

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am able to splice specific rows in a dataset (table), but how do I slice or display specific columns only? Subsets?
This [:2] selects dictionary rows, but not columns:

In:

```
  data4= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data["meta"]['stepInfo'][:2])
  data4
```

Comment: you can do `data4['column_name']` to get the values in a specific column. If you want to get first 10 rows only, you can do data4.head(10). What do you want specifically? Specific columns only? then just do as I said earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You can access any columns by name. Let's call, for instance, your dataframe **df**, and you want to retrieve columns A and B:

```
df[["A","B"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use data.iloc function to select any number of rows or columns you would like, please refer to the link below:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html
For Eg:

```
# For Rows:
data.iloc[0] # First row of dataframe 
data.iloc[1] # Second row of dataframe
# For Columns:
data.iloc[:,0] # First column of dataframe 
data.iloc[:,1] # Second column of dataframe 
# First 4 rows and 5th, 6th, 7th columns of a dataframe
data.iloc[0:4, 5:8]
```